# Extract all rows form table to text

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the following code to extract all rows from my table to a text file.
I am facing a issue. If the value is empty, I am getting the previous row value for that column.
Here is my code.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim strQry As String
Dim aRow(1 To 16) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long

lCnt = 1
ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)

strQry = "SELECT * From tbllast"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
    Do While Not rec.EOF
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)                       
        aRow(1) = rec("cust_id")                        
        aRow(2) = Format(rec("app_date"), "yyyy/mm/dd")  
        aRow(3) = rec("work_id")                         
        aRow(4) = rec("app_price")                       
        aRow(5) = rec("doc_id")                          
        aRow(6) = rec("ass_id")                          
        aRow(7) = rec("pla_id")                          
        aRow(8) = NULL                             
        aRow(9) = NULL                            
        aRow(10) = rec("app_memo")              
        aRow(11) = rec("fin_price")                      
        aRow(12) = NULL                            
        aRow(13) = rec("pay_id")                         
        aRow(14) = rec("receipt")                        
        aRow(15) = rec("fin_memo")   
        aRow(16) = Format(rec("app_date"), "yyyy/mm/dd") 
        aBody(lCnt) = "('" & Join(aRow, "','") & "'),"
        rec.MoveNext
        Debug.Print aBody(lCnt)
    Loop
End If

aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt)

Debug.Print Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
```

I am facing the problem in all columns.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Nz* on all fields that could be *Null* to return an empty string instead:

```
aRow(1) = Nz(rec("cust_id").Value) 
... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if a value is null before writing it with IsNull and maybe assigning it an empty string with ''. You can use the Nz function to achieve this:

`aRow(1) = Nz(rec("cust_id").Value)`